# how does this informal proof show a particular PKE scheme is secure against non-adaptive memory attacks?

Tags: cryptography, machine-learning, matrix-equations

On pg. 5 of [this paper](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~vinodv/AGV-proc.pdf) the author does a section on the "Idea of the proof" using a technique known as [dimension reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction).  The actual proof is on pg. 13 Section 3.1 of the same paper.  However, I am already struggling with the more simpler "idea of proof" section on pg. 5.  The author tries to show that attacking a particular public key encryption scheme with secret key length $N=n log q = O(n log n)$ is semantically secure against non-adaptive memory attack.

Following is my understanding:

1. $s$ is the secret key vector and $h(s)$ outputs some (not all) bits of secret key $s$
2. $m$ [LWE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_with_errors) samples are taken ($a_i, <a_i,s> + x_i mod q$).  I think this means $m$ is an approximation of $A$.
3. $a_i$ represents the $i^{th}$ row of $A$
4. Mental experiment: Let matrix $A$ = $BC$
5. Two observations are made

   - $h(s)$ is small but $s$ still has considerable [min-entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy)
   - matrix multiplication is a strong [randomness extractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor)
6. Putting two observations above together author says $t=Cs$ is random.
7. The resulting expression now looks like $Bt+x$

I understand steps 1-4 above but I'm completely lost in 5-7.  I do not understand how the two observations made in step 5 are helpful or lead to step 7.  I would appreciate it if someone could shed some light on 5-7.

Also, I'm not sure how step 7 proves anything? Somehow it shows that non-adaptive attack will not work with this particular public key encryption scheme?

Comment: "attacking a" $\:\mapsto\:$ "a particular" $\;\;\;$ ? $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer - Yes, I made a change to my post.  The paper is talking about a particular PKE encryption scheme.

Comment: @RickyDemer - Good point, I have made the change.